# JavaScript date Picker / Calendar - Showing Wrong Current Date

Tags: javascript, wordpress, datepicker

URL where issue occurs: http://themartinirepublic.com.s122140.gridserver.com/reservations/

Says it's January 2018...

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you improve this question? There is simply nothing here at the moment.

Comment: Have you checked the server has the date set correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `startDate` to `startDate:"<?php echo date('d/m/y'); ?>"` in your JavaScript, using PHP to get the current date, e.g.

```
if( jQuery.datepicker ){
    jQuery(".cf_date").datepicker({startDate:"<?php echo date('d/m/y'); ?>", buttonImage: "js/calendar.gif", buttonImageOnly: true, dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" });
} else {
```

Comment: not sure, but i'm far from js/ php savvy- i did take a look in the code regarding what you mentioned, and updated the code, but had no luck. here is the file, if you wouldn't midn taking a look - http://www.mediafire.com/?e85963n72qj3qs3

Comment: Remember that for any updates you make to an active WordPress plugin file, you need to deactivate that plugin and then reactivate it before the changes will be in effect.